# Suppose $X,Y$ are r.v.'s sampled from a discrete uniform distribution without replacement. How can I find the joint moment $E[XY]$?

Tags: probability

Suppose without replacement $X$ is taken from a uniform discrete distribution with of support $1,\ldots,M$. Then suppose $Y$ is also taken as a second draw. How can I find a formula for the joint moment

$$
E[XY]
$$
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[XY|X]]=\mathbb{E}[x\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]]$$

... can you go on?

The result I found is

$$E[XY]=\bigg[\frac{M+1}{2}\Bigg]^2-\frac{M+1}{12}$$